# Solving a 1st order homogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $(1):y'-a(x)y=0$.

This is the way I am used to solving those :

$\frac{y'}y=a(x)$

$\ln\left({\frac{y}{|\lambda|}}\right)=\int a(x)=A(x)$

$y=\lambda e^{A(x)}$

Several people have told me that this method was not rigorous enough. (especially when I use $\ln$, as $y$ can be $0$ at times.) It has however always worked with me.

What exactly is wrong with this method, and why does it still give good results ?

What is a way to 'fix' this method, while keeping it short ?

Comment: It has good results because $e^{\text{constant}}\colon =\lambda$ brings back the $0$ case. You could multiply both sides by $e^{-ax}$ and form a reverse product rule, solve with laplace transform or transform it into a total D.E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the given equation

$y' - a(x)y = 0; \tag{1}$

it is a linear, first order system for $y(x)$.  If we can assume $a(x)$ is continuous, then the key to the success of using the integral

$\int \dfrac{dy}{y} = \int \dfrac{y'}{y} dx \tag{2}$

in deriving the solution

$y(x) = y(x_0) e^{\int_{x_0}^x a(s) ds} \tag{3}$

to (1) lies in the fact that solutions to (1) are *unique*; this in turn follows from the fact that the "driving term" $f(y, x) = a(x) y$ occurring in (1) is continuous in both $x$ and $y$ and Lipschitz continuous in $y$ as well.  That meeting these criteria ensures uniqueness of solutions to (1) is a well-known and standard result in the theory of ODEs; the reader seeking greater detail may consult Jack K. Hale's *Ordinary Differential Equations*, chapters I-III or the appendices of the text by Hirsch, Smale, and Devaney.  ***In any event***, uniqueness works for us in the present context as follows:  it informs us that the only solution to (1) which takes on the value zero *anywhere* is identically zero, *everywhere*, since $y(x) = 0$ is the *only* solution with $y(x_1) = 0$ for *some* $x_1$.  Taking things a step further, we can conclude that $y(x) > 0$ for all $x$ precisely when $y(x_0) > 0$, since $y(x)$ can then never cross or even touch the $x$-axis.  Similarly, $y(x) < 0$ for all $x$ precisely when $y(x_0) < 0$, and for the same reason. It follows that exploiting the integral (2) is legitimate in deriving (3) except when $y(x_0) = 0$; but in that case, we know that $y(x) = 0$ *a priori*, from the uniqueness argument just presented; there is nothing to calculate or derive.

When $y(x_0) > 0$, hence $y(x) > 0$, the integral (2) may be used directly as is; if $y(x_0) < 0$, so that $y(x) < 0$, then we may by linearity replace (1) with the equivalent equation

$(-y)' - a(x)(-y) = 0, \tag{4}$

together with the initial value $-y(x_0) > 0$; the solution to (4) is clearly

$-y(x) = -y(x_0)e^{\int_{x_0}^x a(s) ds}; \tag{5}$

negating (5) yields the usual expression for $y(x)$.

It follows from the preceding remarks that exploiting the integral (2) to derive the solution to (1) is a completely rigorous and legitimate technique,  with the sole *caveat* that the case $y(x_0)$ be handled seperately; but as we have seen, *that* case is the simplest of all.  Of course, the approach suggested by mookid in his/her answer covers all cases at once.  Indeed, evaluating $y(x)e^{-\int_{x_0}^x a(s) ds}$ at $x_0$ yields $y(x_0)$ as the constant value this expression takes, so once again we obtain

$y(x) = y(x_0)e^{\int_{x_0}^x a(s) ds} \tag{6}$

as the solution to (1).

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 1):

The big issue is that you have to *justify* that you can divide by $y(x)$. It can be tricky.

A rigorous and very easy
approach is simply to guess (using this method, for instance) 
that the solution has the form $Ce^{A(x)}$, 
and to write on your exam paper, only that
$$
x\to y(x) e^{-A(x)}
$$is constant (because its derivative is $0$).